# Invalid Argument when mounting /system as (RW)

Tags: terminal, android, root

I have Kingroot (for root access) and Terminal emulator installed on my device.

I am using the following command to mount the `System` directory on terminal:

```
mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /system
```

and it says `invalid argument`.

So I tried the following command:

```
mount | grep system
```

and then I get:

> ```
> /dev/block/platform/mtk-msd.0/by-name/system /system ext4 ro, seclabel, relatime,data=ordered 0 0
> ```

Then I execute the following command:

```
mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /dev/block/platform/mtk-msd.0/by-name/system /system
```

but then I get an `Invalid Argument` as a result again.

Why do I get an Invalid Argument and how do I mount the `/system` directory?

Comment: What’s wrong with `mount -o remount,rw /system`? There should be no need to specify the filesystem or the block device. That being said, you might well be unable to mount `/system` r/w outside recovery.

Comment: @DanielB: Android's built-in 'toybox' variant of `mount` _is_ much more picky about its syntax, compared to the more common 'util-linux' and 'busybox' variants. I also remember the one-path syntax didn't work for me, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `man mount`, the `-t` flag should come before the `-o` flag, so:

```
$ mount -t ext4 -o rw,remount /dev/block/platform/mtk-msd.0/by-name/system /system
```

Comment: I still have Invalid argument. . .